# setfacl equivalent to chmod for setting/unsetting individual flag

Tags: permissions, chmod, setfacl

Using `setfacl` command line arguments, is there a way to set/unset **a single flag** as the following command will do ?

```
chmod g+x FILE
```

Please note that:

```
setfacl g::x   FILE
setfacl g::--x FILE
```

are equivalent and will set executable bit **and remove** read a write flag. And thus these commands are not setting/unsetting an individual flag but 3 flags at once.

Comment: Using effective rights mask `setfacl -m m::rw FILE` - off, and `setfacl -m m::rwx FILE` - on - and this way with setfacl is designed to work like

Answer (score 1):

What about using effective rights mask:

```
[test@abcdef ~]$ setfacl -m g::rwx test/
[test@abcdef ~]$ getfacl test/
# file: test/
# owner: test
# group: test
user::rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::---

[test@abcdef ~]$ setfacl -m m::rw test/
[test@abcdef ~]$ getfacl test/
# file: test/
# owner: test
# group: test
user::rwx
group::rwx                      #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
setfacl -m g::x FILE
```

Comment: No, this won't change only the executable permission. Your proposed command is equivalent to ``setfacl -m g::--x FILE``: setting executable bit BUT REMOVING read and write flag.